# How can I rename object keys in a TypeScript type or interface?

Tags: typescript

I have a query driver that relies on proxies and primitive objects. Roughly speaking, it works likes this...

```js
// WHERE Get(a, fromB) is some query string constructor
const _fromB = new Proxy(
    fromB, // proxy fromB
    {
        get : (target, prop, receiver)=>{

             return new Proxy(
                 Get(prop, target), // Proxy dot syntax to form a Get query on gets
                 // ... a recursive proxy handler
             )
        }
    }
)
```

So, that the query writer can...

```js
const query = _fromB.a
```

In order for the driver to work, several properties must remain on the objects produced; they must not use the standard proxy method (logic excluded above).

However, I still want to provide support to Proxy get members that may share the same as a primitive prop. To do this, I've come up with an escape syntax (prefixing the member name with `!`).

To represent this in TypeScript, I believe I need a mapped type that looks something like this...

```js
export type EscapedMemberT<T extends string> = `!${T}`
export type EscapeMappedT<T extends {
    [key : string] : any
}> = T & {
    [EscapedMemberT<key> in T] : T[key]
}
```

Such that an object,

```js
{
   ToJSON : objectMethod,
   a : aProxy
   b : bProxy,
}
```

Would be represented as the type...

```
{
    ToJSON : objectMethod,
    "!ToJSON" : typeof ToJSON,
    a : typeof a,
    "!a" : typeof a,
    b : typeof b,
    "!b" : typeof b
}
```

Or, in other pseudo,

```js
export type EscapeMappedT<T extends {
    [key : string] : any
}> = {
    ...{
        [key in T] : T[key]
    }
    ...{
        [`!${key}` in T] : T[key]
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here. COuld you please add an expected result? Does it https://tsplay.dev/w14EyW work for you?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I've added some more detail. The fiddle you sent is not quite what I'm after.

Comment: Where can I get `a` in order to obtain `typeof a`?

Comment: @captain-yossarian from the T passed to EscapeMap<T>.